# How does django middleware work?

Tags: python, django

I want to ask that if django middleware classes run by each request from clients or they are usable from request object.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It runs from the handler, nothing to do with the request object, Your question is unclear.. what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry , Let's suppose this "http://example.com/contact" , which function of django would handle it and run the views. what is the handle function? Is it middlewares or sth else?

Comment: its the WSGIHandler class (or a custom implemented one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#init)

> Unlike the `process_*` methods which get called once per request, `__init__` gets called only once, when the Web server responds to the first request.

Of course that will apply also to variables stored in object - they will be shared between requests.

Note that it will be per thread / per worker, not per whole project.